# formula returns multiple values crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a formula in CR to display a check box and show which values were selected.

The DB stores the values as such: `1&2&3…&10&11...` if multiple values are selected.

This is not a problem as long as the number of possible values is less than 10. If the selected values are 10 or above the formula selects the correct value but also selects any other values that contain either number. (i.e. if the selected value is 12, the formula for '12' is checked but also the formulas for '1' and '2' also become checked.

Here is the formula for the checkbox:

```
if isnull ({form.table})then CHR (168)else
if instr({form.table},"1") > 0
    then CHR(254) else CHR(168)
```

What is the best way to ensure only the selected values are checked if the value is 10 or above without also selecting the other lower number values?

Do I need to loop thru the values, split on the `'&'` and compare to the selected value? Not too savvy with CR syntax and need to know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

your though is correct... you need to split and then run the loop to get the required output

```
Local NumberVar i;

for i:=1 to UBound(Split ({form.table}, "&")) Do
(
if Split ({form.table}, "&")[i]>0
then CHR(254) else CHR(168)
)
```

This should be the syntax. Actually I don't have tool to test the syntax now but this should work.

If you face any issue leave a comment will test and update the syntax tomorrow incase wrong

Answer (score 0):

Due to the variety of possibilities for values, I needed to be sure there were no null values, check for single numeric values, check for values separated by an &, then check that only a single values was selected and not other values that were part of the selected value. 
It took some trial and error, but I was able to modify the loop example above and perform all of the checks I needed. Here is the formula I came up with:

```
Local StringVar box:= CHR(168);
Local StringVar fld:= {table.field};
Local NumberVar sel:= 11; 
Local StringVar ssel:= "11";

if fld <> "" then
(
    if instr (fld, "&") <= 0 then
    (
        if instr(fld, CStr(ssel)) > 0 then
        if CDbl(fld) = sel
        then
            box := CHR(254)  
    );
    if instr (fld, "&") > 0 then
        (

        Local NumberVar i;

        for i:=1 to UBound(Split (fld, "&")) Do
        (
            if instr(Split (fld, "&")[i], CStr(ssel)) > 0 then
            if CDbl(Split (fld, "&")[i]) = sel
            then
                box := CHR(254) 
        )   
    );

);

box
```

Seems to work as needed so far. Will update if any issues arise.